# Using `gdalwarp` to generate a binary mask?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

Suppose I have a satellite image formatted as a `.tif` file and a `.kml` file that contains a series of polygons that define an area of interest in this image. Now I can run:

```
gdalwarp satellite.tif satellite_aoi.tif -cutline aoi.kml
```

This will extract a new `.tif` image that only has the area of interest specified by the `.kml` file.

Now instead, what I want to do is perform the same area cut out but for the output, I want the areas of interest to be a mask. That is, I want the output of those regions to be a constant white color and preferably an image with a single channel. Is it possible to do this with `gdalwarp`? I looked at the documentation and I could not find any command to do what I need.

Comment: It sounds like you want to rasterize your .kml file. I believe you can do that with gdal_rasterize, but if you want the extents to match the satellite.tif file, you'll have to set them. Otherwise the output will have the same extents as the set of polygons in the kml file.

Comment: Yeah I need the extents to match the satellite.tif file. I tried gdal_rasterize but wasn't sure how to get the extents to match.

Comment: It looks like you've got a solution that works, so no need to bang your head on it. I would get the satellite raster extents in python using the geotransform and raster size. You can also set your resolution to match using the geotransform output. Finally, I would use the -tap switch when calling gdal_rasterize to make sure the pixels aligned. All in all, it would be considerably more code than what you've posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far I know, it's not possible to accomplish the task you need only with `gdalwarp`. Here's a working solution in Python (it requires GDAL 2.1.0+):

```
from osgeo import gdal

vector_layer = "mask.shp"
raster_layer = "raster.tif"
target_layer = "mask.tif"

# open the raster layer and get its relevant properties
raster_ds = gdal.Open(raster_layer, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
xSize = raster_ds.RasterXSize
ySize = raster_ds.RasterYSize
geotransform = raster_ds.GetGeoTransform()
projection = raster_ds.GetProjection()

# create the target layer (1 band)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
target_ds = driver.Create(target_layer, xSize, ySize, bands = 1, eType = gdal.GDT_Byte, options = ["COMPRESS=DEFLATE"])
target_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
target_ds.SetProjection(projection)

# rasterize the vector layer into the target one
ds = gdal.Rasterize(target_ds, vector_layer, burnValues = [1])

target_ds = None
```

Comment: Is it possible to rasterize each individual polygon as a different burn value?

Comment: So I am using an older version of gdal `1100100` and there doesn't seem to be `gdal.Rasterize`. There is `gdal.RasterizeLayer` but I cannot get it working. Does it still work for this version? I tried `gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], target_layer, burn_values=[1])` and I get `TypeError: in method 'RasterizeLayer', argument 4 of type 'OGRLayerShadow *'`

Comment: Alright I tried: `ds = gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], ogr.Open(vector_layer).GetLayer(0), burn_values=[1]); target_ds = None` and I get `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

Comment: But yeah I have to use version `1.10.1` and can't really change it :S

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution I can think of in Python (not the most efficient but works)...

```
shutil.copy('satellite.tif', 'ones.tif')
ds = gdal.Open('ones.tif', gdal.GA_Update)
data = ds.ReadAsArray()
im_mask = np.ones((data.shape[1:])) * 255
ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(im_mask)
ds.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(im_mask)
ds.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(im_mask)
ds = None

command = 'gdalwarp ones.tif satellite_aoi.tif -cutline aoi.kml'
os.system(command)
```

Comment: Although for this solution I output 3 bands when I really only need one...